# Layer.get_weights() returns wrong output with shape(1, 1, 1, 2080, 1536)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I have only added the output layers of the default keras imported inceptionresnetv2 and am trying to visualize the filters present in it ,to do this i am trying to extract the weights and biases using the code below but am getting an array with the shape(1, 1, 1, 2080, 1536) instead of being able to extract the weights and biases into two separate variables, the code returns the error

**not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

please let me know how i can extract the weights and biases for a specific layer

Code:

```
layer_name='conv_7b'
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[0].layers])
filters, biases = np.array(layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights())
```

Model:

```
resnet = InceptionResNetV2(
    input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3),
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet"
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    resnet,
    
    Flatten(),LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05),
    Dense(512,activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.5),
    
    Dense(64,activation="relu"),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(7, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Is there any possibility the layer you call has no bias?

Comment: @andersen it should have a bias, as it is the last convolution layer of the network,and it works in predicting the output accurately,i am trying to use the bias to help visualize the layer activation map but am unable to do so.even if it didn't have a bias it still cant explain the final shape of what .get_weights() returns.